# Unable to put buttons on frame?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm using currently Intellij to create a GUI with 3 buttons on the top of the main frame. I'm fairly new to GUI's and still learning as I go. When I try to run the code I get an error telling me that I cannot have the main method as static but if I remove the static I get an error saying I need it to be static. Is there a way to easily avoid this?

```
package CA3;

import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.*; import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; import java.awt.event.ActionListener; import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter; import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Attach window listener
        addWindowListener(new WindowCloser()); // Just in-case it's needed

        // Adding first customer panel
        JPanel pCustomerL = new JPanel();
        pCustomerL.setBounds(0,0,750,750);
        pCustomerL.setBackground(Color.BLUE);


        // Adding second customer panel
        JPanel pCustomerR = new JPanel();
        pCustomerR.setBounds(750,0,750,750);
        pCustomerR.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        // Adding first invoice panel
        JPanel pInvoiceL = new JPanel();
        pInvoiceL.setBounds(0,0,750,750);
        pInvoiceL.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        // Adding second product panel
        JPanel pInvoiceR = new JPanel();
        pInvoiceR.setBounds(750,0,750,750);
        pInvoiceR.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        // Button Listener
        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        // Adding "Customer" Button
        JButton b = new JButton("Customer");
        b.addActionListener(listener);
        add(b);
        b.setBounds(1300,10,150,35);
        // Adding "Product" Button
        b = new JButton("Product");
        b.addActionListener(listener);
        add(b);
        b.setBounds(1150,10,150,35);
        // Adding "Invoice" Button
        b = new JButton("Invoice");
        b.addActionListener(listener);
        add(b);
        b.setBounds(1000,10,150,35);


        // Adding first product panel
        JPanel pProductL = new JPanel();
        pProductL.setBounds(0,0,750,750);
        //pProductL.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        // Adding second product panel
        JPanel pProductR = new JPanel();
        pProductR.setBounds(750,0,750,750);
        //pProductR.setBackground(Color.BLACK);


        // Frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(1500,750);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // Add panels
        frame.add(pCustomerL);
        frame.add(pCustomerR);
        frame.add(pProductL);
        frame.add(pProductR);
        frame.add(pInvoiceL);
        frame.add(pInvoiceR);

        // Customer Panel Settings
        pCustomerL.setVisible(true);
        pCustomerR.setVisible(true);
        // Product Settings
        pProductL.setVisible(false);
        pProductR.setVisible(false);
        // Invoice settings
        pInvoiceL.setVisible(false);
        pInvoiceR.setVisible(false);
    }

    // Listener for buttons
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            String buttonLabel = evt.getActionCommand();
        }
    }

    // Listener for window
    class WindowCloser extends WindowAdapter {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) { System.exit(0);}
    }
}
```

Comment: [Create a new dialog](https://i.imgur.com/HccoEmv.png) using IDE to see how the code is organized. Notice that in the static main method the new instance of the class is created where all the components are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your code inside the main to another method not-static or you can put it on a Constructor. The errors are because you are using normal methods like **addWindowsListener** which inherits from JFrame. And you also have to remove:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

That's not necessary because your class already inherits from JFrame so your code must be like this:

```
public class Main extends JFrame
{

public Main(){
    // Attach window listener
    addWindowListener(new WindowCloser()); // Just in-case it's needed

    // Adding first customer panel
    JPanel pCustomerL = new JPanel();
    pCustomerL.setBounds(0,0,750,750);
    pCustomerL.setBackground(Color.BLUE);


    // Adding second customer panel
    JPanel pCustomerR = new JPanel();
    pCustomerR.setBounds(750,0,750,750);
    pCustomerR.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    // Adding first invoice panel
    JPanel pInvoiceL = new JPanel();
    pInvoiceL.setBounds(0,0,750,750);
    pInvoiceL.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    // Adding second product panel
    JPanel pInvoiceR = new JPanel();
    pInvoiceR.setBounds(750,0,750,750);
    pInvoiceR.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    // Button Listener
    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
    // Adding "Customer" Button
    JButton b = new JButton("Customer");
    b.addActionListener(listener);
    add(b);
    b.setBounds(1300,10,150,35);
    // Adding "Product" Button
    b = new JButton("Product");
    b.addActionListener(listener);
    add(b);
    b.setBounds(1150,10,150,35);
    // Adding "Invoice" Button
    b = new JButton("Invoice");
    b.addActionListener(listener);
    add(b);
    b.setBounds(1000,10,150,35);


    // Adding first product panel
    JPanel pProductL = new JPanel();
    pProductL.setBounds(0,0,750,750);
    //pProductL.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    // Adding second product panel
    JPanel pProductR = new JPanel();
    pProductR.setBounds(750,0,750,750);
    //pProductR.setBackground(Color.BLACK);




        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(1500,750);
        

    this.add(pCustomerL);
    this.add(pCustomerR);
    this.add(pProductL);
    this.add(pProductR);
    this.add(pInvoiceL);
    this.add(pInvoiceR);

    // Customer Panel Settings
    pCustomerL.setVisible(true);
    pCustomerR.setVisible(true);
    // Product Settings
    pProductL.setVisible(false);
    pProductR.setVisible(false);
    // Invoice settings
    pInvoiceL.setVisible(false);
    pInvoiceR.setVisible(false);
   this.setVisible(true);
}

 // Listener for buttons
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String buttonLabel = evt.getActionCommand();
    }
}

// Listener for window
class WindowCloser extends WindowAdapter {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) { System.exit(0);}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new Main();
}
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a million for helping, it's been a little stressful learning for a project due but your help was definitely appreciated, helped me get back on track :)

Comment: You are welcome! And as the another user comments it's better to use the features of IDE's. They will help you a lot! 
And about the errors you have, I recommend you read about static methods and not-static and  inheritance, to know how they works , in case you don't know it.